# File loads slowly with many optionButtons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel file I have recently completed. It contains 7 empty TextBoxes, 3 CommandButtons (2 will go away once I sign off this document) and 37 OptionButtons. Everything is working great. The macro code isn't too large (195 kb) but it takes about 15 seconds to load.

Is there a way to make it load faster?

Comment: What events are triggered in Workbook_Open()?

Comment: I am forcing it to make a specific sheet active when it opens as sometimes the save leaves it on another tab.  It also clears all TextBoxes and sets all RadioButtons to false. But that code was the last thing I added. It was still opening slowly when I had half the RadioButtons in it and half the code.

Comment: That seems reasonable but still, 40 objects shouldn't cause that much of a delay. To remove all doubt about conflicting events on your main tab you can disable all VBA (make a copy of the file, remove all code and see how long it takes to open)

Comment: Do you have a lot of volatile formulas (e.g. Rand())? That could potentially be an issue. Setting a radio button to false could change a cell content (if it is linked to a cell) and cause all of the volatiles to recalculate. Perhaps your Workbook_Open() event could start by disabling automatic calculation and screenupdating (restoring them at the end)

Comment: No volatiles that I know of. None of the Buttons or textboxes is linked to anything. Simple if-thens in the code to determine which of 4 buttons in 9 groups is  choosen then return the number of correct versus wrong answers. This is all part of a quiz program. Think I'll try the code removed option when I get back to work in the morning. As I recall it was lagging from the start with no code in it. Generated the Excel sheet with controls then the code. Guess I'll  find out tomorrow. Do some more experimenting with it.

Comment: I did it out of curiosity: 7 TextBoxes, 3 CmdButtons and 40 OptionButtons - it opens instantly. Most likely it's caused by events that trigger each other in a recursive way. If it opens fast without VBA you'll have to step through the code as the file opens. To do that you'll need a break point in Workbook_Open() but it's not possible to have one after you close the file. A fast way to stop the code before executing the first line is to type an "x" (invalid text) before the first line of code and it will stop with an error when you open the file, remove the invalid text then continue stepping

Comment: Another possibility is that some objects can get corrupted. If that's the case you'll have to export all VBA, import it in a new file, then recreate all objects and rename them. You cannot simply copy all objects from one file to the other because you'll also get the corrupted object, and it will still be corrupted in the new file (a bit tedious but at least you don't have hundreds of them)

Comment: Dumped ALL the code and it still opens  in like 25 seconds. So I guess I'll try the "Recreate" option and then see what happens. Grouping the OptionButtons wouldn't do that would it? I actually renamed a few as I was copying them since they were numerically out of order when they were copied. Would it be best to just add new OptionButtons rather than copy them?

Comment: Well I did that and it still loads slowly, so I tried something else as well.  I did not mention this file is saved on the network drive.  I saved a copy onto my local drive and as @paul bica it opens almost instantly. However, as an empty sheet with JUST the controls and a few cells with text it still loads slowly from the network drive.  The fully coded file also loads almost instantly from the local drive.  So I guess the issue is NOT with my file but with our network server.  Dare I approach IT about it now is the question. LOL

Comment: :) I never open files from shared drives, exactly because of this reason. Even if I have to open a file temporarily from VBA code, I make sure to copy the file locally, open it, process it, then delete it rather than opening it from a shared location. Good luck with your IT! (easier to ask users to simply copy it locally first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the same file opens almost immediately on a different PC elsewhere on the network even with double the OptionButtons. I think the switch that sections off to my area is going bad or just my port. Might be something else too. Either way it works ok on other PCs so I am calling it good. Need to test out the switch and ports now. Fun fun.